# "Provided to us" or "Provided us"?

Tags: prepositions

Both the sentences/fragments below appear to be grammatical.

> - Thanks for the help you have provided to us in the planning
> - Thanks for the help you have provided us in the planning

Is there actually any difference? Are both really grammatical? What difference (if any) does *to* make?

Comment: You also omitted the first "the" in your second sentence. Was this intentional?

Comment: There is no difference. One is from a relative clause _you have provided help to us_ and the other is from a relative clause _you have provided us help_. Relativization removes _help_, leaving either the prepositional phrase _to us_ or the dative-shifted _us_ (with no preposition).

Comment: I've rewritten this question because we can't tell you what you should write. But we **can** explain the use of the preposition in each sentence (as @JohnLawler has done). I hope he'll write an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The grammar aspect has been sufficiently addressed by John Lawler in the comments.

> There is no difference. One is from a relative clause you have provided help to us and the other is from a relative clause you have provided us help. Relativization removes help, leaving either the prepositional phrase to us or the dative-shifted us (with no preposition). – John Lawler

These [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=provided+to+us+in+*%2C+provided+us+in+*&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cprovided%20to%20us%20in%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bprovided%20to%20us%20in%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprovided%20to%20us%20in%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cprovided%20us%20in%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bprovided%20us%20in%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprovided%20us%20in%20his%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprovided%20us%20in%20this%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprovided%20us%20in%20our%3B%2Cc0) show that there is a slight popularity advantage for the variant without *to,* both in individual occurrence as in number of ngrams found at all. Dwelling on the popularity for a moment one might also show these [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=provided+to+us+*%2Cprovided+us+*&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cprovided%20to%20us%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bprovided%20to%20us%20by%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprovided%20to%20us%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprovided%20to%20us%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprovided%20to%20us%20as%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprovided%20to%20us%20through%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprovided%20to%20us%20at%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprovided%20to%20us%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprovided%20to%20us%20and%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprovided%20to%20us%20from%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprovided%20to%20us%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cprovided%20us%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bprovided%20us%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprovided%20us%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprovided%20us%20by%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprovided%20us%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprovided%20us%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprovided%20us%20horses%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprovided%20us%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprovided%20us%20all%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprovided%20us%20an%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprovided%20us%20of%3B%2Cc0) showing the overwhelmingly more popular usage of *provided us with.* Thus, one could say the most idiomatic wording of your sentence would be this:

> Thanks for the help you have *provided us with* in/during the planning ...